# Javascript function that finds match in an array

Tags: javascript, function, for-loop, methods, logic

I'm beginning to learn Javascript, and I want to create a function that can sort through an array and compare two values (probably string values).

For example, if there are 50 different words, but there are two "banana" words, I want to know that. Any help on this would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you need help with? What do you know / have you done so far? Do you know how to access an array? How to iterate over it? Do you know that arrays have a `sort` method? We can't really help you without info about your situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` to find all items that satisfies a filter function. I believe that by *sort*, you meant *traverse* or *iterate*.

E.g.

```
var words = ['test', 'banana', 'banana', 'other'];

var bananaCount = words.filter(function (word) {
    return word == 'banana';
}).length;

console.log(bananaCount); //2
```

> The function needs to work without explicitly stating the word
>   'banana'. The function needs to find 'banana' programmatically - *Team6Labs*

Well, you can just adapt the above exemple:

```
countOfWord(words, 'banana'); //2

function countOfWord(words, word) {
    return words.filter(function (w) {
        return w == word;
    }).length;
}
```

Comment: The function needs to work without explicitly stating the word 'banana'. The function needs to find 'banana' programmatically.